# Replace Video track src with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I have the following variable called url which is equal to the below blob which is a vtt file

```
url = "blob:https%3A/d1d7b857-3364-4a21-868c-f4a9580c5e2c...."
```

and the following video page

```
<video id="gump" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="forrest_gump.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <track src="subtitles_en.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" label="English">
</video>
```

I would like to replace the subtitle track src with the above url using JS or Jquery. I was wondering what the best way to do this is.

Something I was thinking was
document.getElementById("gump").src = url but doesnt seem to work as i need to get the track src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<video id="gump" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source id='mySource' src="forrest_gump.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <track src="subtitles_en.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" label="English">
</video>

document.getElementById("mySource").src = url
```

Put an id on the actual source element and target it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `<track>` element `src` attribute takes the url of the vtt file, just set it to that

```
$('#gump track').prop('src', url);
```